# Why does my VirtualBox VM not appear in VBoxManage list vms, but re-creation fails

Tags: virtualbox, docker

I created a VirtualBox VM `FreeBSD-11.1-amd64` with `/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage createvm --name FreeBSD-11.1-amd64` which was successful according to the output

```
Virtual machine 'FreeBSD-11.1-amd64' is created.
UUID: c71b2a99-6d87-460e-98ab-6baa2db94e54
Settings file: '/root/VirtualBox VMs/FreeBSD-11.1-amd64/FreeBSD-11.1-amd64.vbox'
```

However `/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage list vms`'s output is empty, but running the creation command above again fails because the VM already exists.

Afaik this only makes sense if the created VM was a cat.

I'm working inside a headless docker instance of `ubuntu:artful` on Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my tests you missed the `--register` option when creating it, so your command aught to have been:

```
 VBoxManage createvm --name "FreeBSD-11.1-amd64" --register
```

With that a `VBoxManage list vms` would have shown that vm. To fix that error register it with this command:

```
 VBoxManage registervm /path/to/file/FreeBSD-11.1-amd64.vbox
```

Now run `VBoxManage list vms` to ensure its now seen by `Virtualbox`